# Why redis rpush rq:queue:example-rq 1 does not work

Tags: redis

Under Ubuntu 18.04 --

```
$ redis-cli info
# Server
redis_version:4.0.9
```

What's magical about `rq:queue:example-rq` that it fails rpush? --

```
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush rq:queue:example-rq 1 
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys * 
(empty list or set)
```

change any one character and it works --

```
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush rq:queue:example-rp 1 
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys * 
1) "rq:queue:example-rp"
127.0.0.1:6379> del rq:queue:example-rp
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> rpush rq:queue:example-qr 1 
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> keys * 
1) "rq:queue:example-qr"
```

Comment: Have you checked that there are no RQ workers popping from that queue?

Comment: You are right sir, some process is popping it